# Мой Ноутбук HP Pavilion g7, на Kubuntu, использует встроенную графику, хотя дискретную он так же видит

Tags: amd, kubuntu

случилась у меня проблема. Старенький ноутбук Pavilion g7, поставил Kubuntu 22.04[image: Kubuntu]

ноутбук использует встроенную видеокарту, хотя дискретная в системе определяется:
[image: Дискретная карточка]